# Remote web server pages do not update after making changes via SSHFS

Tags: apache, google-chrome, sshfs

I've been troubleshooting this for a while now and can't seem to find a solution. I have a remote LAMP server in my office and sometimes need to work from home. I use a SSHFS between my home computer and work to accomplish this.

However, I have run into an issue where when I update the local files, the changes get pushed to the server immediately as they should. I have verified that the changes are there via SSH and VIM. However, if I refresh and even force refresh the page in Chrome the changes do not appear.

I also created a local file which showed up immediately on the server and I could view in Chrome, but any subsequent changes to the file are not rendered.

Any time that I'm in the office the changes are rendered immediately as well.

Anybody have any ideas?

- Apache 2.4.7
- Sublime Text 3 Editor
- Client SSHFS: win-sshfs 0.0.1.5
- Server SSH: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the modified time isn't updated correctly on the remote filesystem. I'm not so sure what would be the fix for this but this at least could be a first trail to follow?

In fact, I just did a little search around and found this bug : https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/issues/detail?id=99

With a possible workaround in Sublime 2, I'll let you check if there is such a setting in Sublime 3

Comment: That was it! I awoke today thinking that it was a modify time issue, so I touched the file as a test and it worked. After disabling the atomic save function in ST3, it's the same as ST2, it solved the issue. Thanks!